# Drupal 7 prepopulate form values for embedded field collection

Tags: 7, forms, entities

I need to prepopulate my embedded field collection values in a specific form.
Here is what I've got so far:

```
<?php
// Hook form alter
function mp3_template_form_alter(&$form, &$form_state, $form_id)
{
  // Pre fill profile mp3 form with mp3 template data
  if (isSet($form_id) && $form_id == 'profile_mp3_node_form')
  {
    global $user;
    $user_full = profile2_load_by_user($user->uid, 'artists_profile');

    // Get field collection entity ids from the user
    $entity_ids = $user_full->field_copyrights_mp3[LANGUAGE_NONE];

    // Load field collection entities
    $entities = entity_load('field_collection_item', $entity_ids);

    // Here I want to prepopulate the $form['field_copyrights_mp3'] form field with my collection items that contain the data for field_copyrights_mp3
    $form['field_copyrights_mp3'][LANGUAGE_NONE][0] = $entities[0]; // 1 field collection
    $form['field_copyrights_mp3'][LANGUAGE_NONE][1] = $entities[1]; // 2 field collection
    // etc...
  }
}
```

I have searched a lot and tried multiple approaches to prefill my field collection with multiple rows of data. Hopefully someone can point me into the right direction of what I should do next.

Image of what I'm trying to prepopulate with multiple owners:
[image]

Answer (score 0):

you can use the [MODULENAME_form_alter](https://api.drupal.org/api/drupal/modules%21system%21system.api.php/function/hook_form_alter/7.x) hook to achieve this, by iterating through its nested array, [maybe this can help](https://www.drupal.org/forum/support/module-development-and-code-questions/2011-11-10/field-collection-with-unlimited#comment-8462791)

If this help, awesome, ping me if not, I can share some snippets that achieve that :)